# Is there a keyboard shortcut for adding a path to AnyLogic?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, anylogic

Noob question.

I'm building an AnyLogic model with a busy network with multiple paths leading to lots of different nodes.

It seems that each Node to Node segment (or segments) requires:

1. Double-click the Path in Space Markup
2. Click node one
3. Click the corners of the path (if any)
4. Click node two.

To do this for a network requires repeating this for each node you're adding.

I wondered if there was a keyboard shortcut for step 1, since that's the biggest mouse move back and forth.

The other thing I found out was that you can double-click on the second node (step 4 above), it allows you to carry on, but it puts the connection at a random spot on the node, which requires you to clean it up.

What are the other possible way to add all these paths to AnyLogic?

Below is an image of the network, still being built. To connect all the blue squares in the top left of the image to the network would seem to require repeating the above sequence of 4 steps 6 times.

[image: SegmentOfNetwork]

So the questions:

1. Is there a keyboard shortcut to get into Path mode (equivalent to double-clicking the Path option int he Space Markup Palette)?
2. A related question: Can you (easily) add a node to two intersecting paths?
3. Are there better tricks for adding a biggish path network (like in the above image)?

Incidentally, I know that ctrl+drag replicates an existing component and that is often more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a keyboard shortcut to get into Path mode (equivalent to double-clicking the Path option int he Space Markup Palette)?

No

> A related question: Can you (easily) add a node to two intersecting paths?

You drag it "between" them

> Are there better tricks for adding a biggish path network (like in the above image)?

Absolutely. You create it 100% via code (or from data). See https://anylogic.help/markup/create-network-by-code.html#create-network-by-code

Alternatively, you have a layout imported, right-click it and let AnyLogic create a network from it.